# i'd like to view a textured model in one pane while deleting a vertices in another pane of the same object

Tags: edit-mode

I have an obj file that is quite large, while deleting vertices from the mesh in edit mode i need to be able to see the textures in another window in object mode.How can i do this?

Comment: Please reconsider title of your question. Maybe - How to view textured model in one pane and edit it in another.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt need to be in object mode. You can have both windows in Edit mode, then just have 1 of them show wire-frame, and the other material or rendered.

[image]

Comment: you little beauty, thank you, new to this stuff, and you just helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks! And no problem what so ever offcourse. If i could just give you 1 piece of advice: stuff like this is covered in basic tutorials. Which leads me to believe you havent watched/read them. Fine, if this is the path you choose to walk, i will be here to help. But i wonder if you really like waiting for 2 days for an awnser that you can find in 1 minute yourself. So concider it bud. Trust me, being a frequent user myself, it will be worth your time! If not, let me know ;).

Comment: yes i know exactly what youre saying and tried watching many tutorials.but i only have one or 2 specific uses for blender as the rest of my work is generated on other software.so i dont need a comprehensive insight into the software.not yet anyway.i couldnt generate for myself a solution to what i needed after all the tutorials so thought the quickest would be to ask. so it did save me a lot of time.so thank you.